# What is the best software to amplify the sound of spoken voice?

Tags: recording, software, voice, audacity

I have a digital voice recorder that has the ability to download the recordings into a computer.

I have recorded conversations that I will need to amplify. What is the best software to do that ?

It seems that Audacity free software would be able to get that done. But that software seems way too complicated and extensive if the only use that I have for it is to amplify voice recordings.

Maybe you know of other software that would be suited - I will probably only need to amplify and not change much else about the recording.

Please do not answer by saying:
 put the microphone of the recorder or the computer harder. You can be certain that I will tape everything at maximum volume level. The speakers of the computer are also already at maximum level but I still have a need to amplify spoken conversation, so a normal voice recording.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: from the Tour things not to ask - "Questions that are primarily opinion-based"

Answer (score 2):

Audacity is actually a very slim program, compared to most other DAWs. I see no reason why you shouldn't use it for this application, in fact it seems quite a good fit. (Apart from the possibility that you might end up needing features *not* contained in it!)

Of course, if all you want is to replay a recorded audio file at more than 0 dB volume (i.e. more than 100%), then many off-the-shelf audio players will also do the trick – [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) would definitely work; [banshee](http://banshee.fm/), [audacious](http://audacious-media-player.org/), good old [winamp](http://www.winamp.com/) should also be able to get the job done. However, I wouldn't recommend that – you may end up using the player also for some fully-mastered music file, which is then loud way into distortion.

A better approach might be to *normalise* all the files, i.e. to gain up each file (without playing it) exactly as much as possible without distortion. I would [do that with `ffmpeg`](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg), but there are [plenty of (probably simpler) tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=batch+audio+normalization) around that do the same thing.

The real question is why these recordings are so quiet in the first place. If you can simply boost them significantly without introducing distortion, it means the gain was not set up correctly while recording. Get a better mic/preamp/recorder, if yours isn't able to do that. Boosting the signal after recording always means you're also boosting the noise.

Quite possibly though, you *can't* actually boost without distortion. Note that a dry vocal recording has a really high [dynamic range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range), which means there are some rather useless loud sounds (e.g. “plop” plosives), but the parts you need for understanding are way quieter. In this case, you need a [dynamic compressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) (and probably an [EQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalization_%28audio%29) too) to get the effective volume to useful levels. Audacity can offer both, so again I'd recommend using that.